# connecting two networks together

Tags: networking

I have two networks

Network A  and a DMZ network, we'll call it network B, they are configured through a sonicwall

Network A has a public IP address ending in .155 or 192.168.10.x internally and network B   has a public IP address ending in .156
or  172.16.10.x internally

is it possible to access network A's public IP address from network B?

My msp says this cannot be done. Network B can't access network a's public IP.

I understand I could edit the host file to force the internal address but this is a laptop and the user will take their laptop home - at that point the internal address is no good.

I have an SVN server configured on that public IP address and don't want the user to have to relocate each time they come in to the office or go home.

Comment: Please clarify about the networks. A network usually contains more than one IP address and has a network mask. If you don’t want to disclose the actual addresses, simply use 10.x.x.x.

Comment: By definition, a public IP address should be available anywhere that has Internet connectivity without any special setup needed (this is what makes it **public**).

Comment: @krowe2 I'm being told by our msp this can't be done

Comment: @DanielB Updated

Comment: Are both networks behind the same modem device (for example, a company such as BT (UK) you can have multiple public IPs through one BT BusinessHub)? If this is the case then you might not be able to access the different public IPs due to NAT loopback not being available on your modem device... A read of NAT Loopback may help explain why it isn't working for you http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16343/is-nat-loopback-on-my-router-a-security-problem

Comment: @BigChris yes, they are. but network A can access network A's public IP address with a loopback

Comment: Can network B access network B's public IP? You may need to look into some routing (if your networking devices support user-editable routing)... I'm no networking guru but I've come across your question problem before so I immediately suspected NAT loopback

Comment: @BigChris yes, B can access B's public address

Comment: http://www.falconitservices.com/support/KB/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=19 - this might be achievable since you use a Sonicwall - I've never used it but it may work... I don't know if your modem device (if different to your Sonicwall) may cause you problems, though...